# Django admin/site_base.html overwrites my admin/site_base.html

Tags: python, html, django

My admin/base_site.html doesn't load or gets overridden by django's admin/base_site.html. Please let me know what I'm missing out (I started recently)

I have my template at

> BASE_DIR/templates/admin/base_site.html

In settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            'debug': True,
            "context_processors": [
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
                "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "account.context_processors.account",
                "pinax_theme_bootstrap.context_processors.theme",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

EDIT: I made a mistake in my question, my template is actually at

> PROJECT_ROOT/templates/admin/base_site.html

where **PROJECT_ROOT** is the directory of manage.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your application is declared before `django.contrib.admin` in [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) of your django `settings.py`

Indeed, Django's template loader will walk through apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` and grab the first matching template as decribed in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader).

> The order of INSTALLED_APPS is significant! For example, if you want
>   to customize the Django admin, you might choose to override the
>   standard admin/base_site.html template, from django.contrib.admin,
>   with your own admin/base_site.html in myproject.polls. **You must then
>   make sure that your myproject.polls comes before django.contrib.admin
>   in INSTALLED_APPS**, otherwise django.contrib.admin’s will be loaded
>   first and yours will be ignored.

Comment: Looks like that would be the case If I put my templates under "myproject/polls/templates/admin" but what if I'm keeping the template at "myproject/templates/admin" ? Shouldn't that also load and overwrite anything loaded before?

Comment: It should indeed because according to the docs the first default loader is `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader` which uses `DIRS`. Did you restart the server after creating the BASE_DIR/templates directory ? Try loading a template from that directory with no name conflicts with other modules to check the server is really looking for templates in that directory... Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change DIRS into

```
"DIRS": [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),
    ],
```

The problem was in settings.

```
"DIRS": [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
    ],
```

here **BASE_DIR** is the directory of the main app, therefore **DIRS** includes **mysite/mysite/templates**

There was a mistake in my question.I thought BASE_DIR is the directory of my project therefore my template was at

> BASE_DIR/templates/admin/base_site.html

but actually it was at

> PROJECT_ROOT/templates/admin (Where manage.py is)